# django rest framework problem with permission classes

Tags: django-rest-framework

I have made a simple project to test the permission classes but it's not working.
when I define these permission classes globally then it worked but when I tried to define it class level then it is not working.
I have checked many times but it's not working 
then I check for compatibility issues but I don't understand 
I am using python 3.8.2 
Django =2.2.5 `
drf version is 3.11
I don't know where is the problem

```
    from django.shortcuts import render
    from testapp.models import Employee
    from testapp.serializers import EmployeeSerializer
    from rest_framework.viewsets import ModelViewSet
    from rest_framework.authentication import TokenAuthentication
    from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated,AllowAny,IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly
    from testapp.permissions import IsReadOnly
    from rest_framework_jwt.authentication import JSONWebTokenAuthentication
    from rest_framework_simplejwt.views import TokenObtainPairView,TokenRefreshView

# Create your views here.
class EmployeeCRUDCBV(ModelViewSet):
    queryset=Employee.objects.all()
    serializer_class=EmployeeSerializer
    # authentication_classes=[TokenAuthentication,]
    authentication_classes=[TokenObtainPairView,]
    # permissions_classes=[IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly,]
    permissions_classes=[IsAuthenticated,]
```

Comment: What do you mean by globally or class level?

Answer (score 0):

'permission' classes not 'permissions', you have a typo ^_^

Example:
https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#modelviewset

Comment: thanks bro for replying.this was also a problem but there was some compatibility issue also.